# Return multiple values from scanf() without requiring 2 or more inputs? C language

Tags: c, scanf

I'm currently in college in a C language class. I always like to make the assignments given to me to be programmed user-friendly and neatly. So, keep in mind I'm beginner level at this stuff.

Although this is basic, I just need help with this:

```
1    int count, sum, max, input;
2    count = 1;
3    sum = 0;
4    input = 0;
5    printf("This program will find the sum of your given 
6          input of an integer.\n");
7    printf("Please enter the number you would like the sum 
8          of: ");
9    scanf("%d", &max, &input);
10   while (count <= max){
11        sum = sum + count;
12        count++;
13    }
14    printf("The sum of %d is %d.\n", input, sum);
15    printf("==To exit the program, please enter anything, 
16          then press enter==");
17    scanf("%d");
18    return;
}
```

I want to let the user know on line 14 of what they entered firstly while also giving them the sum of what they entered. How can I do this?

EDIT: I know that line 9 makes no sense, but that's where I am having the issue. I have seen scanf("%d%d", &var, &var);, but that requires the user to have 2 inputs. I only want 1 input. In other words, if a user inputs a number, I want that only 1 input to go into both `max` and `input`.

EDIT 2: For example, if you input to want to have the sum of `10`, I want line 14 to show the input you entered as well as show the sum of `10`.

Comment: Post example inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: If there is only one input, what are `max` and `input`?  Are both of them to be set to the single value that is entered?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I provided an example with an edit. Sorry for that.

Comment: @WilliamPursell The problem I'm having is when I want to have one input, it doesn't properly show. Like in the example that I edited in, if you enter 10, the program will say ```The sum of 0 is 55```. I want to have 10 be in the placement 0 is, but I don't know how to do that without having to require 2 inputs. EDIT: So I guess what you said is what I mean. I want both ```max``` and ```input``` to be the single value that is entered.

Comment: @Barmar Okay, so like say the user inputs ```10``` for the input variable. Is what you are explaining is to put a function statement like ```input = max;``` so that ```max``` also has the value of ```10``` that was returned to ```input``` from the use of the ```scanf();``` function?

Comment: You cannot use any input function correctly unless you **check the return** to VALIDATE the input either succeeded or failed. You must do this BEFORE you attempt to use the variable you attempted to fill with the input. Additionally  you only need 1 `printf` per-continual block of output (not one per-line), e.g. `printf("The sum of %d is %d.\n==To exit the program, please enter anything, then press enter==", input, sum);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf()` will only assign to as many variables as there are format operators in the format string. The extra variable you provide is ignored, it doesn't get a copy of the same input value.

Use an ordinary assignment to copy the entered value into the second variable.

```
scanf("%d", &max);
input = max;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont need to declare an extra variable "input".(Since the value of max never changes in your code.)

Just check the below code:

```
1    int count, sum, max;  //removed input
2    count = 1;
3    sum = 0;
4                    //removed input
5    printf("This program will find the sum of your given 
6          input of an integer.\n");
7    printf("Please enter the number you would like the sum 
8          of: ");
9    scanf("%d", &max);
10   while (count <= max){
11        sum = sum + count;
12        count++;
13    }
14    printf("The sum of %d is %d.\n", max, sum); //replaced input by max
15    printf("==To exit the program, please enter anything, 
16          then press enter==");
17    scanf("%d");
18    return;
}
```